# How can I convert corrupted old data or broken charset in database to UTF-8?

Tags: mysql, encode, charset

I have a database, but the data in it is not UTF-8 compatible and shows Turkish characters broken. I need a detailed help on how to translate data automatically or manually. I've tried everything, but can't figure out how to replace broken characters with compatible ones.

[post subjects looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRA3Q.png)

There are too many symbols that I can't replace.

Comment: Reverse the insert, if you haven't lost some bits, then insert the data again but this time use utf8 all the way

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: A photo gives not enough detailed information to give you detailed help. which encoding do you use?

Comment: latin1 rn but I want to convert all entire old data to UTF-8

Comment: That's Mojibake -- see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given us much information to work from, but assuming you have been inserting UTF-8 data into latin1 columns over a latin1 connection you can do the following.

Given a posts table like:

```
CREATE TABLE posts (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    subject VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    body TEXT NOT NULL
) DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

You can create a new table like:

```
CREATE TABLE posts_utf8 (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    subject VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    body TEXT NOT NULL
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

And then populate it with:

```
INSERT INTO posts_utf8
SELECT id,
    CONVERT(BINARY subject USING utf8mb4),
    CONVERT(BINARY body USING utf8mb4)
FROM posts;
```

If you are happy with the content of the new table you can then switch them over:

```
RENAME TABLE posts TO posts_old, posts_utf8 TO posts;
```

Comment: There are several different ways to "fix" bad characters; be sure to test this first.